# Is there non-linear gameplay with multiple ending?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Can the player make choices that affect the story and may result in multiple endings, or does it consist of going through linear levels while always telling exactly the same story?

I do not count such things as modifying weapons or your gear as relevant. I also am not interested if I can defeat foes in different ways or avoid them altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the game is extremely linear - there is always only one path to take, and only one ending.

However, don't let this scare you off:  the storyline and atmosphere are amazing, and definitely worth playing.

Also, since you mentioned it:  you can mod your weapons, and in some cases choose to fight, avoid, or (sometimes) run away from enemies.  There are also many different ways to fight enemies, if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 5):

The Last of us [wiki](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_of_Us) has a section on game-play that says:

> The gameplay will be "less linear" than the Uncharted series, even though it will not be open-world. Instead "the exploration will be more important and will have enough weight in the gameplay.

Whilst the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us) page on the last of us describes the plot, in detail so many spoilers, to be linear.

So from the looks of things, you cannot change the way the game ends, but you can take a few different paths, (literal paths through buildings or a subway ect), to get there.

Comment: Really? The game is fairly linear with some exploration within the same area. If you want to move from one area to the next however, there is always just one way. There is no choice of which path to take. I don't think you've actually played the game?

Comment: Parts of it, perhaps not enough to see as much as you see

Comment: I agree with this answer. The methods you choose and approaches you take to move through the sections of the game will be different every time and between players. Yes, each section has a start point and end point, but the options in between are quite varied.

Comment: deutschZuid, I think you have misread RhysW's answer. He/She answered that there is some choice to the actual paths you take through "buildings or a subway". That is true. For example, in the building at the quarantine area, the one before the hotel chapter, there are multiple ways to get to the second floor. Ultimately you must exit at the fire escape at the back of the second floor, but your path there is somewhat flexible. But, yeah, I'd hardly call it non-linear. And there is little difference, in this regard, from the Uncharted series.